# How to append two urls together via rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm a complete rewrite newbie and I'm lost. We need to pass a URL and append it to the end of another URL. For example: If I go to www.site1.com/x_x_x/xxx/xxxxxxxxx/file.pdf I need it to be passed and appended to a 2nd URL. It should look like this: www.site2.com/?remoteurl=www.site1.com/x_x_x/xxx/xxxxxxxxx/file.pdf

This is what I have so far: `RewriteRule /([a-z0-9-]+)([a-z0-9-]+)([a-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]{3})/([0-9]{9})/([a-z0-9-]+)([a-z0-9-]+)([a-z0-9-]+)[A-Z]{2}.pdf$ https://site2.com/?remoteUrl=http://site1.com/(missing code goes here?) [QSA,NC,R]`

The first part works perfectly. Any file I go to will match correctly and get forwarded to the second URL. Obviously I'm missing the crucial part of appending. I feel like an idiot for not being able to figure this out. I've tried a few stuff I found online but nothing is working for me.
I'm not sure if that's even the correct way of doing this.

Comment: Format your code using `{}` button to make it more readable.

Comment: Just did. Thanks for the FYI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^ http://example2.com?remoteurl=%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R,NE]
```